# With twitter bootstrap, how to have thumbnail (as in the thumbnail component) have the same height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

You can see here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails in the example with a title and a description, if the title or the description of one the cell is much shorter or longer than the other, the whole height of the block will be diminished or increased accordingly.

How to have these block having the same height?

I tried with setting `display: table-row` on the `ul`, and `display: table-cell` on the `.thumbnail` class, but unfortunately this completely borked the responsiveness of the layout: the image height and width inside the block are not resized automatically any more.

UPDATE: setup a demo of the problem on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kwBuW/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can fix the height div which has got the thumbnail class. Like:

```html
<div class="thumbnail" style="height: 400px;">
```

If you want the same height for every content, I think you must write a JavaScript which will fix it, after the DOM ready of course. Like:

```js
var max = 0, jThumbnails = $("ul.gallery div.thumbnail");
jThumbnails .each(function(index, elt){
    max = Math.max(max, $(elt).height());
});
jThumbnails.setHeight(max);
```

Comment: Yep of course, I could set the height for the block. But I don't know the height in advance, because it depends on the content... And then, there's the javascript solution... On twitter someone mentionned http://tsvensen.github.com/equalize.js/

Comment: I know this plugin. It works fine. But this is really simple to do it. So I prefer write my own code :)

Comment: I see a problem with your JS solution: it will work on the first page load, but not if the user resize the browser window later.

Comment: You will have the same problem with equalize.js. Listen the "resize" event on window.

Comment: Finally I did this :

    displayTableCell = () ->
      max = 0
      jThumbnails = $("ul.thumbnails li .thumbnail")
      jThumbnails.height("")
      jThumbnails.each (index, elt) ->
      max = Math.max(max, $(elt).height())
      jThumbnails.height(max)

    $(document).ready () ->
      displayTableCell()
      $(window).on 'resize', () ->
       displayTableCell()